# Actualizar un registro si existe si no insertar en sql

Tags: mysql

hola estoy tratando de crear una condicional en el que se pueda actualizar e insertar, el motivo es que quiero que al modificar una formula se pueda no solo cambiar cantidades si no agregar mas artículos, la parte de actualizar es la única que me funciona, pero quisiera agregar condicionales para cuando guarde realice esas operaciones alas dos tablas.                                .

```
$sql = "update detalle_Dproducto
      set 
      numero_Dproducto=?,
      productoc=?,
      id_Mprima=?,
      materiales=?,
      unidadm=?,
      moneda=?,
      precio=?,
      cantidad=?,
      importe=?,
      id_usuario=?,
      id_producto=?,
      estado=?
      where
      id_detalle_Dproducto=?
      ";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1, $numero_Dproducto);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $productoc);
    $sql->bindValue(3, $id_Mprima);
    $sql->bindValue(4, $materiales);
    $sql->bindValue(5, $unidadm);
    $sql->bindValue(6, $moneda);
    $sql->bindValue(7, $precio);
    $sql->bindValue(8, $cantidad);
    $sql->bindValue(9, $importe);
    $sql->bindValue(10, $id_usuario);
    $sql->bindValue(11, $id_producto);
    $sql->bindValue(12, $estado);
    $sql->bindValue(13, $id_detalle_Dproducto);
      $sql->execute();
    }
    $sql2 = "update Dproducto set
    numero_Dproducto=?,
    productoc=?,
    rinde=?,
    costo=?,
    categoria=?,
    moneda=?,
    subtotal=?,
    estado=?,
    id_producto=?,
    id_usuario=?
    where
    id_Dproducto=?
    ";  
    $sql2 = $conectar->prepare($sql2); 
    $sql2->bindValue(1, $numero_Dproducto);
    $sql2->bindValue(2, $productoc);
    $sql2->bindValue(3, $rinde);
    $sql2->bindValue(4, $costo);
    $sql2->bindValue(5, $categoria);
    $sql2->bindValue(6, $moneda);
    $sql2->bindValue(7, $subtotal);
    $sql2->bindValue(8, $estado);
    $sql2->bindValue(9, $id_producto);
    $sql2->bindValue(10, $id_usuario);
    $sql2->bindValue(11, $id_Dproducto);
    $sql2->execute();
  }
```

Comment: ¿Eso no lo puedes comprobar con tu variable `$id_detalle_Dproducto`? Si tienes su id es que el producto existe, ¿no?

Comment: asi es, entonces seria con if y else ?

Comment: Sí, así mismo. Si tienes el id lo modificas y, si no lo tienes, lo insertas y obtienes ese id para posteriores modificaciones

Comment: Gracias por la información y tu conocimiento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), aunque para ello la llave que usaras necesitaría tener el atributo UNIQUE

```sql
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  column1 = VALUES(value1)
```

Otra solución sería con un [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db_name.upsertTable1;
CREATE PROCEDURE db_name.upsertTable1(
    IN value1_in VARCHAR(255),
    IN value2_in SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    ...
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE id_var UNSIGNED INT DEFAULT 0;
    # Seleccionando el id de tu registro (si es que existe)
    SELECT id INTO id_var FROM table1 WHERE column1 = value1_in AND column2 = value2_in 
        AND ...

    # Si no existe el registro lo insertas
    IF id_var = 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO A (column1, column2, ...)
        VALUES (value1_in, value2_in, ...);
   # De lo contrario actualizas el campo
   ELSE
       UPDATE table1 SET column1 = value1_in, column2 = value2_in, ...
       WHERE id = id_var;
   END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Y te aseguras que el usuario tenga permisos de ejecución sobre ese procedure

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db_name.upsertTable1 TO 'your_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Y para llamarlo sólo usas [CALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html)

```
# Si no existe lo inserta
CALL upsertTable1("Am I already registered ?", 2, ...);
# Si ya existe lo actualiza
CALL upsertTable1("Am I already registered ?", 3, ...);
```

Comment: Gracias por la información y tu conocimiento